# BigCommerce Stencil error on checkout.php - loader.png

Tags: bigcommerce

We created a custom Stencil theme for a client. Before the launch, we previewed the site on a Sandbox account. The loader.png icon on checkout.php worked fine on the sandbox URL.

On the live site, a 404 error is showing for loader.png when the checkout page is loaded and the a broken image icon is showing where the image should be.

`https://cdn2.bigcommerce.com/server4300/2c996/templates/__custom/images/loader.png?t=1425093818 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

The loader.png icon is in assets/img/loader.png in our local files, but since the checkout page is locked down, we don't see how to include the correct path or image for this icon. What's strange as well is that it works in the Sandbox store, but not the live store. We don't have access to the file directories to add loader.png into the location where the error says it does not exit.

The path in the sandbox store is different which I believe is the issue.

`https://cdn3.bigcommerce.com/r-39561e43f8711d17fc99f3b25f5101b446f75650/themes/Stencil/images/loader.png`

Can BigCommerce Stencil support update the path so this image loads correctly? I have a support request in to update us from CP1 to CP2. I'm not sure if that has something to do with it or not, but that may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this issue, our checkout.php page had to be reset by BigCommerce. Once it was reset the loader.png showed up correctly.

Comment: Did you ever find out what the root cause of the issue was? I'm having the same problem with product thumbnail images on the checkout page. Bigcommerce is outputting an invalid image URL resulting in a 404. I will ask them to reset checkout.php as you said, but I'm concerned that when I launch the theme in production, the same issue will occur. Do you have any insight on this?

Comment: After the checkout was reset, we didn't have any more issues even after updating the theme multiple times. I believe it had something to do with switching from an old BC theme to a Stencil theme. I had more success with the developer advocate, than the first-tier support.

Comment: How do I get in touch with a developer advocate? This sounds like someone I desperately need quite often.

Comment: I was contacted after posting here. You may want to open a support ticket about this issue as well if you haven't already.